# Close Vote Review Audits are too obvious

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, vote-to-close, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

The other day, I got an obviously good question in a Close Vote Review.  Even if I didn't read the question, [+11 with 3 answers](https://serverfault.com/questions/494986/use-windows-dhcp-dhcpv6-server-without-setting-a-static-address) is a bit of a giveaway.  Today I got one where [the question was almost incomprehensible.](https://serverfault.com/questions/495206/a-lot-of-opening-tables-in-processlist-of-mysql)

Also, on sites other than SO (where I understand the queues are huge), the number of reviews needed is often low enough (single digits) that you usually notice when you get an extra one.

I don't mind - I'm quite happy to get easy-to-pass audits - but maybe they could be a little harder...

Comment: @gnat if a full page of review audit questions doesn't get the message across 2 pages isn't going to either

Comment: @RichardTingle sorry about that, I forgot that I usually split such tagging into smaller amounts

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While you have a good point, I don't think you quite understand the point of audits.

Audits aren't there to make you read the question, they're there to stop robo-reviewers. They are *supposed* to be easy. Since robo-reviewers aren't going to stop to read it anyway why make it hard for the *real* reviewers?

This has actually been discussed several times in these questions as well:

[The robo-approvers are killing my will to review edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155561/the-robo-approvers-are-killing-my-will-to-review-edits)

[Are the suggested edit audits too easy?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171204/are-the-suggested-edit-audits-too-easy)

[Fix review audits to make them more robust against robo-reviewers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165118/fix-review-audits-to-make-them-more-robust-against-robo-reviewers)

Answer (score 6):

As suggested in some duplicate bug reports regarding this issue, close and reopen review audits with known bad (closed) questions do not contain the closed notification anymore so that the audit is less obvious.

Comment: This is apparently [still happening](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188661/180276) - is this rolled out yet?

Comment: Only the known bad question audit was updated. The question you linked to is asking about a known good question audit.