# Audit has shown too much detail about the post making the audit obvious

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

Story:

While doing some reviews on Close-Votes on SO I've been presented a question to review that got a

> This question was closed by xxx, yyy, zzz

footer. I was surprised, but still I've reread the question and decided to agree, pressed "Close" and it turned out to be an audit. Passed of course.

Bug/suggestion:

I think that the footer should not show up. Obviously, Close-Vote reviews would probably not show threads that are already closed, so that makes the audit instances quite obvious **in this review category**. Those footers are still perfectly valid in audits in Reopen category!

Comment: Got  one as well but I chose to close and failed the audit so the correct answer is not obvious but it is obviously an audit

Comment: As reported on [su] Meta [Bug on /review already closed](http://meta.superuser.com/q/6912)

Comment: @Mark also, the audit is easily passable by visiting the question directly.

Comment: @JanDvorak: indeed, that is true I think for all audits. I quite often visit the original question just to recheck its state, read answers and comments and so on, before finally deciding on whever to close or not. But, after reading [see this explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/178195/195816), I no longer see it as a serious issue. It required some wits and understanding. On the other hand, a text "question closed by" on the footer makes it trivial for robots to parse it and pass the audit ;)